# Attempting to pull API data and embed video within a react js file

Tags: reactjs

Like the title says, I'm having trouble embedding and getting the video to show from the nasa api. I've tried iframes but the video is not showing. How can I add to my code to make this work? I would like to note the video is being displayed is a youtube video.

```
             <div>
             <iframe width="560" height="315" title={props.title} src={props.url} frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            

    
             
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm embedding youtube video in my React project.

Note that some videos cannot be embedded in iframe, if the owner forbids.

And the only way to embed youtube video is using iframe.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const YoutubeEmbed = ({embedId}) => (
  <div className="video-responsive">
    <iframe
      width="853"
      height="480"
      src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`}
      frameBorder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
      allowFullScreen
      title="Embedded youtube"
    />
  </div>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <YoutubeEmbed embedId="rokGy0huYEA"/>
    </div>
  );
};

class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <App/>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.video-responsive {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
}

.video-responsive iframe {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```